# How to handle missing variable panic properly?

Tags: go

I have the following simple go-lang code.

```
aud := claims["aud"].(string)
```

It's a jwt claim so it always exist. Then I was trying to experiment on changing the variable from aud to missing-aud.

When I changed it, then tested. I noticed a critical panic.

> [PANIC RECOVER] interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not string goroutine 7

What is the simplest way to handle a missing variable and not panic?

I have tried, but it seems not the case.

```
var aud string
    if claims["audx"].(string) != "" {
        aud = claims["audx"].(string)
    }
```

Thanks for anyone who could help

---

Modified with an answer, but was looking if this could be simplified?

```
    var aud string
    if _, found := claims["audx"].(string); found {
        aud = claims["audx"].(string)
    }
```

Comment: Please take the tour of Go again, the section on [maps](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/22) covers tests for existence. You should also perform your type assertions using the two-return format.

Comment: ahhh ! v, ok := m["Answer"]

Comment: Thanks! can this be simplified? var aud string
 if _, found := claims["audx"].(string); found {
  aud = claims["audx"].(string)
 }

Comment: Found myself repeating claims["audx"]

Comment: Sorry, did not get the type assertion @JimB?

Comment: Type assertions in the tour: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15, in "Effective Go": https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions, and the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JimB pointed out - you are confusing type assertion (`claims["audx"].(string)`) with a map-key existence check (`v, ok := claims["audx"]`):

If your map value is of type `interface{}` - then yes you need type assertion. But you also want a key check before you check the value e.g.

```
if v, ok := claims["audx"]; ok {

        log.Printf("audx key exists")

        if vs, ok := v.(string); ok {
            // "audx" value is a string
            aud = vs
            log.Printf("audx value is a string: %q", aud)
        }

}
```

This playground example should make it clearer: https://play.golang.org/p/pTOR39wDCx5

Comment: An example like this is really better to understand. thank you for helping and taking time to point out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The form of your `if` statement is valid, and would work here, but the `found` value is not what you are expecting. It is the result of the type assertion, rather than the map index.

```
_, found := claims["audx"].(string)
```

can be broken down as

```
v := claims["audx"]
_, ok := v.(string)
```

Since the zero value for the type assertion is valid for your purpose, and you are taking no action on the result of the index or assertion conditionals, you can simplify the expression to:

```
audx, _ := claims["audx"].(string)
```

This works because if the map returns `nil`, the type assertion simply fails, but will give you the zero value of that type.